# Why am i getting two different answers about which version of Python 3 do i have installed on Ubuntu 18?

Tags: command-line, python3

If i type "python3.7 --version" into terminal: result is: Python 3.7.3
If i type "/usr/bin/python3 -V" into terminal: result is: Python 3.6.7
Since this entry i installed pip and then ran "python --version" as advised by https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-python-from-the-command-line
result now is  Python 2.7.15rc1
I am trying to learn Python from scratch.  I am using Visual Studio Code and i have run into a problem.  When i run terminal in Visual Studio Code; which version of Python will it be using?

Comment: What Ubuntus version?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 uses 3.6.7 by default, so this is the expected result from running `python3`—because `/usr/bin/python3` linked to python 3.6.7.

You can link it to your desired python version, but this is not preferable way because it might break things and create incompatibility. Instead, you can create alias to make `python` command behaves as your desire python version.

```
emmet@ansmachine:~$ alias python=/usr/bin/python3.7
emmet@ansmachine:~$ python --version
Python 3.7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The "which" command can be useful for things like this, it will tell you the pathname of the file that will be executed by a given command.

For example:

```
which python
```

tells you which file will be executed by the "python" command, and

```
which python3
```

tells you which file will be executed by the python3 command. Since you appear to have a separate python3.7 command you can check that also using

```
which python3.7
```